# MySQL 5.0 broken on snow leopard. How to get data into new 5.1 version?

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, migration, mysql5

I've seen some similar questions but I am still a bit unsure on what I need to do.  I had Mediawiki installed on Leopard.  I then Upgraded to snow leopard which broke MySQL.

Everything seems to indicate that I need to backup the db then import it.  However since the 5.0 version of MySQL is DOA I don't have the facilities to do this.  I installed mysql-5.1.53 (64-bit) hoping it would bring my data over but no luck.

I think Mediawiki stores data in an InnoDB format by default so I don't think I can just copy over the data directory over (at least that's what I understand from what I have seen).

Ultimately I want to get this data off of the Mac and onto an Ubuntu server I built.  How do I want to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a fresh install of MySQL 5.0 on that machine?  If you have all the innodb data files intact, it *might* work.  There's no straightforward way to do this.

You've probably learned the importance of backups from this, which is good.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I managed to get a fresh install on the machine and I was able to export the data.  I really would have expected the db files themselves to be just fine as backups.  I also would not have expected snow leopard to mess with my database without also upgrading my data or at least warning me.   I'd vote you up if I had the rep.